# Calendar system like Google Calendar in Python

Tags: python, calendar

Algorithm of this problem was already discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611/designing-a-calendar-system-like-google-calendar) question.

As that post said, the biggest challenge is handling re-occurring events. And *don't reinvent the wheel* in the first answer, so I would only glad to know:

**Is there any ready-to-use modules or frameworks already, to deal with this in Python?**

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the actual Google Calendar?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: You mean other than privacy and security?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'm using this system to do other things too, for example scheduled email-notification for websites. And we have to send calendar notifications to mobile devices located in China, which have not really reliable link quality to google's services.

Answer (score 1):

I recently build a Google calendar-like app for Django. Although we didn't include re-occuring events yet, I think this should not be too difficult. I suggest looking into [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), which can do quite some nice interval things ussing rrule.

For the front-end we used [jquery week-calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki) which gives you nice drag/drop/resize stuff. We also used [Vobject](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/) to create iCal feeds, so users can incorporate our calendar into their prefered calendar client.

Comment: Hmm, thanks anyway, but I'm JUST stuck at the re-occurring part :-(